# Is the following statement true about dense open sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am just wondering if the following statement is true? I was thinking about using it to prove that the countable intersection of dense open sets is open.  The statement is:

If M is a dense open set in $\mathbb{R}$, then it contains all of its intervals. That is, if $x,y \in M$, then $[x,y] \in M$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: That's clearly false: otherwise it would be an interval itself.

Comment: The only dense subset of $\mathbb R$ with that property is $\mathbb R$ itself.

Comment: A countable intersection of dense open subsets of $\Bbb R$ is generally not open. Example. Let $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$  Let $A_n=\Bbb R$ \ $\{q_n\}. $ Then each $A_n$ is dense and open. and $\cap_{n\in \Bbb N}A_n=\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$ is open and dense and the interval property fails a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

$(\mathbb R \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{\dfrac {1}{n}\})\setminus \{0\} $ is open and dense and the interval property fails a lot of times in one interval.

Comment: And $ℝ \setminus ⋃_{n=1}^∞ \{\frac1n\}$ is a countable intersection of open dense sets that is not open.